# Parallel lines in a vector illustration

Tags: vector, illustration

I’m creating a stencil as a vector illustration (in Vectornator), and I’ve been struggling to create parallel curves for the outline. Is there a common the technique for this, other than just obsessively tweaking the control points so that the curves seem as parallel as possible? I’m attaching an image with what I’ve got so far. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In most editors you can copy + paste (or duplicate) things like this. Or at least copy the relevant part of the rendered SVG and then change the points

Comment: if you draw a line give the stroke some width and if the software has a convert to path it will do this

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I've never heard of Vectornator - but if it has a way to turn strokes into outlines, and has boolean operations like other vector image editors such as Illustrator/Inkscape - the you could use these to combine paths with solid areas.   This is basic vector software functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the online manual of Vectornator. It can convert strokes to outlines which can be combined to other paths. Vectornator use many same operation names as Illustrator. An example:

[image]

1. A single open curve with quite wide stroke
2. The stroke is outlined (I do not know if you must ungroup the result and remove the original curve). It's now a closed path which has a narrow stroke, no fill
3. Another path is drawn
4. Both paths are united to one with pathfinder - It's the boolean union.